# Mavericks issue: flickering when replacing subviews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, calayer, osx-mavericks

In my app there are some areas where I want to animate a view. However, I don't want to make the view layer-backed . So, I created a second view (let's call it animationView) that hosts a layer that I then animate . Of course , to get the animationView to look like the actual view, I first render the view into an image , that I then set as the contents of the root layer of animationView. When all that is done, I replace the view with animationView. At this point I have all the power of CALayer animation available to me without making the actual view layer backed. Here's the code I've been describing (I'll get to my problem in a minute):

```
// Creating an animationView
NSView* animationView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: self.bounds];
animationView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
animationView.layer = [CALayer layer];
[animationView setWantsLayer: YES];

// Snapshotting the actual view
NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect: view.bounds];
[view cacheDisplayInRect: view.bounds toBitmapImageRep: imageRep];
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: [imageRep size]];

[image addRepresentation: imageRep];

// Replacing the view with animationView
NSDisableScreenUpdates();

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
layer.contents = image;
[CATransaction commit];

[self replaceSubview: view with: animationView];

NSEnableScreenUpdates();

// Animate animationView
// ...
```

This works perfectly on 10.8 and the animation on 10.9 also plays very well, BUT on 10.9 ONLY there is a visible flicker when replacing views. Even after using NS[Disable|Enable]ScreenUpdates, I have that problem. I also tried removing the entire animation code after `// Animate animationView`, so that no animation played and I made sure the flicker wasn't from the animation, but actually from the action of replacing the views. And still the flicker persisted. I really don't understand why the difference between OS versions... Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

It Sounds like there's something crazy in Mavericks. Did you try:

```
[self.window disableFlushWindow];
[self replaceSubview: view with: animationView];
[self.window enableFlushWindow];
```

Also, I noticed you're replacing the subview 'view' here, but you're replacing 'view' with the contents of 'self'. What's 'view'?

Also, you don't need to call both:

```
animationView.layer = [CALayer layer];
[animationView setWantsLayer: YES];
```

Also, just call:

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
```

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet, but I will, thanks for the advice. I'll tell you later how it went. Sorry about that self/view confusion, my mistake: where I had self I actually meant to have view. Also, thanks for the tip on CATransaction! Had missed that from the docs.

Comment: Also, about the `setWantsLayer` method call, the docs state that: `To create a layer-hosting view, you must call setLayer: and supply your layer object before you call the setWantsLayer: method; the order of these method calls is crucial.` I assumed this meant one needs to call both methods, in that specific order. Are you saying I only need to call `setLayer`?

Comment: Right, but if you're just going to set it to be a generic CALayer, you're much better off just calling "animationView.wantsLayer  = YES" and letting the AppKit machinery create a custom layer for you. The docs are for when you want to use a custom layer subclass (like CATiledLayer).

Comment: Aaaaaa, I see! That makes sense, yes. Thanks for clarifying that point!

Answer (score -1):

Please try to replace your subviews in main queue (in this case using GCD and blocks). This may solve your problem.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Your action here
});
```

Comment: The entire code is running on the main thread (runs when a button is clicked), so that cannot be the source of the problem.

Comment: OK, will try to reproduce this issue and come back soon :)